# How to match value from scala Map

Tags: scala, match

I am new to scala and was working with Maps. I do a get on Map, but I am not sure how to check for the return type and use it. 
I have following code which gives following compilation error "Pattern Type is incompatible with expected Type: TestClass.type required Option[TestClass].

```
object MapOptionUsage extends App {
 val map : Map[Int, TestClass] = Map[Int, TestClass]() 
 var i = 0
 for(i <- 0 to 5){
   map.put(i, createObj(i))
 }
 var a = map.get(5)

 a match {
     case TestClass => {//dosomething
    }
     case None => {//dosomething
    }
   }
   def createObj(i: Int): TestClass = {
     return new TestClass(i)
  }
}
case class TestClass(val id: Int)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get()` returns `Option[]`, and `TestClass` takes a constructor parameter, so you have to match for both those things.

```
case Some(TestClass(x)) => {//dosomething
```

BTW, good Scala code doesn't use `var` or `return`.

Comment: It worked. But one more question. How do I get this in a variable Some(TestClass(x)), so that I can use that inside case block?

Comment: `case Some(TestClass(x))` will match an `Option[TestClass]` and `x` is a variable containing the `id` value. `case Some(x)` will match any `Option[]` and `x` is the variable holding the `TestClass` (in this case). `case x` will match any value and `x` is the varable containing that value.

Answer (score 1):

There's several issues.

1. , your map is immutable, you can't put things inside a immutable map.
   `val map : mutable.Map[Int, TestClass] = mutable.Map[Int, TestClass]()`
2. is `case Some(x)=> {//dosomething` Since the return is an Option, you need a Some type to match against.
3. is `def createObj(i: Int): TestClass = {` needs to be defined on your object, not inside your match statement.

Edit: To address comments.

```
case Some(x)=> {//dosomething
    System.out.println(x.id)
}
```

Will match and create a new value, where x is equal to the contents of Some, that is, the TestClass contained inside the map.

Comment: sorry I missed the import but I am using a mutable map, and createObj is not defined inside match.

Comment: 2. is still valid. and 1 and 3 were wrong inside your question. 

Some(x) will match where x is your TestClass Some(TestClass(x)) will match x to the int.

Comment: Don't import mutable.map it will confuse scala readers who read your code.